# ngCordova watchPosition is not working in ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I 'm working on an app in ionic framework in which I want to get location of device.
It works fine for **getCurrentPosition**
But when I try to use **watchPosition**, so that I can get new position whenever there is a change in location of device. it does nothing.
I 'm not sure what I 'm missing 
my controllers.js code

```
.controller('LocCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaGeolocation) {
  var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
  $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
      alert('Latitude: '        + position.coords.latitude        + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
    }, function(err) {
      alert(err);
    });

  var watchOptions = {
    timeout : 3000,
    enableHighAccuracy: false // may cause errors if true
  };
  var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
  watch.promise.then(
    null,
    function(err) {
      alert("error:"+err);
    },
    function(position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude
      var long = position.coords.longitude
      alert("Lat in Watch:"+lat);
  });
  $cordovaGeolocation.clearWatch(watch.watchId);
})
```

I used some alert messages to see whats happening,
In current setuation, it gives two alert messages giving **getCurrentPosition**, but noting happens on changing device Location.